# Manipulate Nifti image using ITK

Tags: c++, vtk, itk

I am trying to write a simple program to read or visualise nifti image using ITK libraries.

```
  using PixelType = unsigned char;
  using ImageType = itk::Image< PixelType, Dimension >;
  using ReaderType = itk::ImageFileReader< ImageType >;
  ReaderType::Pointer reader = ReaderType::New();
  reader->SetFileName(argv[1]);
  reader->Update();
  ImageType::Pointer image = reader->GetOutput();
```

From these code lines, I can access number of dimensions, and pixel type. But, I am still lost how I can access the pixels values of the image? I imagine I should have 3D array contains different values of pixels (which represents the nifti image). Which methods I should address?

Also, I have tried to use VTK to visualize the image, and create new format (PNG, or PPM) for the image, but I couldn't do it. Any code example is much appreciated. Thank you!

**Edit:**

I can now get the pixel values after casting the DS PixelType to int. Thank you.

But, When I used the class `ImageToVTKImageFilter.cxx`, I got the screenshot attached, where I can't see any image. And it gets brighter if I moved the mouse over it. Do you have any explanation for that?

[image: image visualization]

Answer (score 1):

You should read ITK software guide, section 4.1.3 Accessing Pixel Data [[link]](https://itk.org/ITKSoftwareGuide/html/Book1/ITKSoftwareGuide-Book1ch4.html#x38-490004.1). [Example](https://itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/IO/ImageToVTKImageFilter) of reading and visualizing a 2D image. Another [example](https://itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/QuickViewDemo) (probably supports 3D images).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you please check my edited post again?

Comment: Can you try using QuickView? Example: https://itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/Visualization/QuickViewDemo

Comment: Have you tried using mouse scroll when you hover over the window? Slice 0 might be visualized by default, and it frequently contains only background (black) pixels.

Comment: I have tried the QuickViewDemo and also same black/white image. Using mouse scroll does only zooming function. Pressing the left button and hovering over the window changes from black->gray->white. I checked the same image using ITKSNAP and it works fine. So, now I am still lost why I can't see it with these simple code lines!!

Comment: Is your image 2D or 3D? Can you provide a complete runnable example?

Comment: The image is 3D, and is nifti type.
I used the QuickViewDemo code used : [here](https://itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/QuickViewDemo)

Comment: QuickView demo there uses 2D image: `typedef itk::Image<unsigned char, 2>  ImageType;`. You need to chage that to 3D to visualized any slice besides the first.